# how to use blitz_0.9

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, blitz++

I down load blitz_0.9,I can build it in vs2008 and get blitzd.lib and blitz.lib
but how can i get blitz.dll
who have used it give me some advice thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't just compile the static version of the library?  If so no .dll will be produced.  Perhaps you can show the commands you used to build the library.

Comment: there is no commands because,I build it follow this :
open the Blitz-Library.sln in vs2005 and click build to build blitzd.lib blitz.lib.  I am sure there is no dll file after build the solution .

Comment: I'm still not sure why you believe a .dll should be produced.  you should be able to look at the project settings to see if a static or dynamic library is supposed to be built.  If it is a static library then there is no problem, you will not get a .dll.  Simply link your application with the .lib files generated.